# how to get store product details using PHP SDK or amazon PAAPI

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I want to get product details i.e. their name,desctiption/features,price,all images(small,medium, large, whichever available),parent category, attributes such as weight, color, etc from amazon.com.

Is this possible by any means?

I am developing a website in php(wordpress) that will show products from amazon.com

I came across amazon aws sdk for php and amazon PA API, but don't know how to use them to get what i want.

Also found Amazon-ECS-PHP-Library but don't don't know how to use it.
Can anyone tell me about any tutorial or any documentation or any kind of resourec that shows how to get the things that i want.

i am registered at amazon affiliate.I see the services available ( like EC2,S3 and other) but not aware of using them.
Please help.

Comment: So basically, you want someone to read the docs for you and provide you with copypaste example for the things you want to do?

Comment: No, what I am saying is that somebody aware of this entire system could help push me in the right direction... that's all, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

The Product Advertising API falls under the Amazon Associates program, which is entirely separate from Amazon Web Services (AWS) which includes Cloud Computing solutions and server architecture.

The AWS SDK for PHP is for AWS, and does not include support for the Product Advertising API.

Since your question is about PHP and the PAAPI, let me move your question to the appropriate forum where you're more likely to get your question answered.